# One Regex pattern but not the other

Tags: regex

I have the sample text below where i need to extract all numbers between  5 and 7 digits, which i can use `[0-9]{5,7}+`

However, I do not want matches that have a prefix `XXX-YYY-2763464823`, which the above expression will catch.

I have been experimenting with negative lookahead and lookbehind with out success. if have tried things like

`(?!XXX-YYY-[0-9]+)[0-9]{5,7}+`  and other variations that did not work.

additionally, once i have the correct match, i will need to delete everything else but the matches themselves.   which can be done with

**(Regex Pattern)|.**   and replace with **(?{1}$1\n:)**

```
562020 (to PORT) 
542029 and attachments to Follow
472306
XXX-YYY-000053379 (to PORT) 
578748 and attachments to Follow
480054
498837 (to PORT) & 1639864 to Follow
463507
XXX-YYY-000053461 (to PORT)
XXX-YYY-000053452 and attachments to Follow
436768
XXX-YYY-000053470 (to PORT) 
210763 and attachments to Follow
96259
XXX-YYY-000053489 (to PORT)  
XXX-YYY-000053478 and attachment to Follow99452
XXX-YYY-000005443 (to PORT)  
XXX-YYY-000005433 and attachments to Follow
XXX-YYY-000053605 (to PORT)  
XXX-YYY-000053590 and attachments to Follow
102742
1094839 (Management Discretionary Approval)
XXX-YYY-000006172 (to PORT)
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: (?<!XXX-YYY-)[0-9]{5,7}+ I think it goes something like this.

Comment: previously tried it, it still captures XXX-YYY numbers.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: trying it in notepad++ and here https://regex101.com/r/28LLzg/1

Comment: I do not understand your question, largely because you have cast it in terms of an example, which rarely results in the question being unambiguous. As I understand, you want to match 5-7 digits in a string provided one or more conditions are met. You need to state those conditions in words, using one or more examples for illustration. A possible requirement is that the string that is matched is not preceded by (let's say) 4-6 digits *and* that the 4-6 digits are not preceded by the string `"XXX-YYY-"`. Let's look an example to show how even that can be interpreted differently...

Comment: ...Suppose the string were `"XXX-YYY-"1234567890123"`. Then would `"90123"` match? It is between 5-7 characters and is preceded by 8 digits. Since 8 is outside the range 4-6 it would seem to match. `"890123"` (6 chars) would also seems to match, but `"78901234"` would not. What about `"89012"`? If this is what you have in mind would you select the longest match, `"890123"`? As I say, you need to state the question so that it is unambiguous. It would also be helpful to shows strings that yield a match (and identify the match) and strings that do not (with an explanation for why they fail).

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to not match something that occurred before the selected digits then that is negative lookbehind.  You would assume that `(?<!XXX-YYY-)[0-9]{5,7}` would do what you want.

But it doesn't because, if the selected digits start after `XXX-YYY-0`, then the negative lookbehind is satisfied (and that is always true unless the `XXX-YYY-` is followed by exactly five digits).

And if you use this `(?<!XXX-YYY-[0-9])[0-9]{5,7}` then, if the selected digits start after `XXX-YYY-`, the negative lookbehind is satisfied (which is always be true).

And you can't put something in a lookbehind that matches arbitrary lengths of digits so you can't protect against both at the same time with one lookbehind.

What does work is `(?<!XXX-YYY-)(?<![0-9])[0-9]{5,7}` because that checks that there is no `XXX-YYY-` before the selected digits AND there are no digits before the selected digits.  And that takes care of both conditions - the selected digits have to be at the start of the digit string and can not immediately follow `XXX-YYY-` which is exactly what you asked for.

However, the other thing is that, if you have a number longer than seven digits without a `XXX-YYY-`, then the regex will match only the first seven digits of the number, which isn't what you want.

So you should use `(?<!XXX-YYY-)(?<![0-9])[0-9]{5,7}(?![0-9])` to get the whole number not following a `XXX-YYY-`.  The regex you want is:

```
(?<!XXX-YYY-)(?<![0-9])[0-9]{5,7}(?![0-9])
```

Comment: Jerry -  Thank  you!!!!!  for the detail explanation. i would have not gotten to this conclusion any time soon.   i will need study it for the next few days!  again thank you.

Comment: My understanding is that the OP wishes to match `"XXX-YYY-12345678901234567890"`, though it is not clear if the last 5, 6 or 7 digits are to be matched. In any event, the regex you suggest does not match. Please explain.

Comment: @CarySwoveland When he said "However, I do not want matches that have a prefix XXX-YYY-2763464823" I assumed that the prefix he referred to was "XXX-YYY-" and that "XXX-YYY-2763464823" was just an example (which is why he was trying to put "XXX-YYY-" into the negative lookahead and not trying to put "XXX-YYY-2763464823" into the negative lookahead)  I didn't think that the fact that he mixed up lookahead and lookbehind was important for the purpose of determining the prefix he wished not to match.  Maybe I misunderstood?

Comment: Jerry, You got it right. the goal was to exclude all digits with a prefix of xxx-yyy_ which the expression  takes care of.  My only question would be why not included the "+"   to cover one or more digits in the expression?  like (?<!XXX-YYY-)(?<![0-9]+)[0-9]{5,7}(?![0-9]+)

Comment: @user68650  To check that the number is all the consecutive digits you only need to know if there is a digit before or after the selected digits.  Knowing there is possibly more than one doesn't add any value.  Plus you CAN'T have an arbitrary length matchs in a lookaround - they must be fixed width.